# DevExpress Components - ASP.NET - not available in any file but master page (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, master-pages

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional with DevExpress components. I have experienced a lot of problems while trying to make this stuff work (VS crashes, unavailable C# asp.net projects etc.). I've re-installed everything many times so I think that's why some configurations got corrupted.

Right now my problem is that DevExpress components are unavailable when trying to add to ASPX source file, the only place I can add them is master page. However I believe this is some bug, because it breaks entire idea of templating websites.

This is my first time working with this set of tools, so please explain it as accurate as possible.

Comment: What version of DevExpress you are using for your page and is it a licensed version?

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18614

Comment: Yes, it is licensed. Anyway -  the problem 'disappeared', not sure why, I was attempting many fixes, nothing helped, but another day it magically worked and continues to the present moment.

Comment: well it's not like pc restart helped, simply I opened visual studio (still no components available) then left it minimized for like 40 minutes, when I maximized the window it was like *poof* and components appeared...